# How can an auto-implemented property having different access levels be described by an interface?

Tags: c#, interface, automatic-properties

This class property is what I'm trying to refactor into an interface.

```
public class Stuff : IStuff {
    public int Number {
        get;
        protected internal set;
    }
}
```

Visual Studio 2008 refactoring tools extract the following interface

```
// Visual Studio 2008's attempt is:
public interface IStuff {
    int Number { get; }
}
```

The C# compiler complains with the error:

```
'Stuff.Number.set' adds an accessor not found in interface member 'IStuff.DataOperations'
```

(This is one of the few circumstances I have run into where Visual Studio generates code that causes an improper compile situation.)

Is there a direct solution to extract this one property into an interface without making distinct set and get members/methods on the class?

Comment: Mine produced the same interface and compiled fine.....

Comment: I see the error when you add the `IStuff` prefix to the `Number` property name....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested with the following:

```
class bla : Ibla {
    public int Blargh { get; protected internal set; }
}

interface Ibla {
    int Blargh { get; }
}
```

and it works just fine. Did you implement the interface correctly?

Comment: Correct - thank you. I think it was a side-effect of having other compile errors in my code.